# How to loop through a list of cities and get temparature for given date with 'weatherData' in R

Tags: r, loops, lapply, weatherdata

I have the following df

```
city <- data.frame(City = c("London", "Liverpool", "Manchester","London", "Liverpool", "Manchester"),
                   Date = c("2016-08-05","2016-08-09","2016-08-10", "2016-09-05","2016-09-09","2016-09-10"))
```

I want to loop through it and get weather data by `city$City` for the data in `city$Date`

```
city <- data.frame(City = c("London", "Liverpool", "Manchester","London", "Liverpool", "Manchester"),
                   Date = c("2016-08-05","2016-08-09","2016-08-10", "2016-09-05","2016-09-09","2016-09-10"),
                   Mean_TemperatureC = c("15","14","13","14","11","14"))
```

Currently I am using `weatherData` to get weather data with the following funtion:

```
library(weatherData)
df <- getWeatherForDate("BOS", "2016-08-01")
```

Can someone help?

Comment: If you need to work rowwise in base R, you can use `apply` with margin 1. Looking at the documentation for that function, it looks like you'll have to look up location codes first, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```
temp <- as.matrix(city)
codes <- sapply(1:nrow(city), function(x) getStationCode(city[x,1], "GB")[[1]])
station <- sub("^[[:print:]]+\\s([A-Z]{4})\\s[[:print:]]+", "\\1", codes)

temp[, 1] <- station

temperature <- sapply(1:nrow(temp), function(x) {getWeatherForDate(temp[x, 1], temp[x, 2])$Mean_TemperatureC})
city2 <- setNames(cbind(city, temperature), c(colnames(city), "Mean_TemperatureC"))

city2
#        City       Date Mean_TemperatureC
# 1     London 2016-08-05                14
# 2  Liverpool 2016-08-09                14
# 3 Manchester 2016-08-10                13
# 4     London 2016-09-05                20
# 5  Liverpool 2016-09-09                18
# 6 Manchester 2016-09-10                13
```

The first step is to get the codes of the different cities with the `sub` and the `getStationCode` functions. We then get the vector with the mean of the temperatures, and finally, we create the data.frame `city2`, with the correct column names.

It is necessary to look for the stations code, as some cities (like Liverpool) could be on different countries (Canada and UK in this case). I checked the results on Weather Underground website for Liverpool, the results are correct.

Comment: thanks, when I use different cities to the example `city <- data.frame(City = c("Hull", "Dartford", "London","Epsom","Chichester","Middlesbrough"),
                      Date = c("2016-08-01","2016-08-01","2016-08-01", "2016-08-01","2016-08-01","2016-08-01"))` the script returns an error, do you know why? I checked the cities individually and they all return data for the period. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it seems that some of those cities do not have a station code. You could try to use `temperature2 <- sapply(1:nrow(temp), function(x) {getWeatherForDate(temp[x, 1], temp[x, 2])$Mean_TemperatureC})` (without using the variables codes and station)